# PHP MYSQL : Printing 2D arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following data inside one of my arrays :

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'ID' => string '1747' (length=4)
      'OWNER' => string 'ME' (length=7)
      'TABLENAME' => string 'MYFIRSTTABLE' (length=15)
      'COLUMNNAME' => string 'MYFIRSTFIELD' (length=11)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'ID' => string '1756' (length=4)
      'OWNER' => string 'ME' (length=7)
      'TABLENAME' => string 'MYFIRSTTABLE' (length=15)
      'COLUMNNAME' => string 'MYSECONDFIELD' (length=12)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'ID' => string '1757' (length=4)
      'OWNER' => string 'ME' (length=7)
      'TABLENAME' => string 'ANOTHERTABLE' (length=15)
      'COLUMNNAME' => string 'ANOTHERFIELD' (length=16)
```

So far, everything is OK: I can loop through each rows and print them in a HTML table.
Something like this:
[image]

Now, I was wondering how to produce something like this:

[image]

I've tried some nested foreach, but without any success.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You want the column names in a different row to the table names?

Comment: Hi Nick, exactly! In fact, for each tablename, I want to retrieve each columnnames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should do what you want. It finds all the table names from the data (using [`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) on the output of [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)), then finds all the column names for each table (using [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), then [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to re-index the keys of the array). It then loops over the tables and columns, outputting a table of table names and their column names:

```
$tables = array_unique(array_column($data, 'TABLENAME'));
$columns = array();
foreach ($tables as $tn) {
    $columns[$tn] = array_values(array_filter($data, function ($v) use ($tn) {
        return $v['TABLENAME'] == $tn;
    }));
}
$max_columns = max(array_map(function ($v) { return count($v); }, $columns));
echo "<table>\n";
foreach ($tables as $tn) {
    echo "<tr><td>$tn</td><td colspan=\"$max_columns\"></td></tr>\n";
    echo "<tr><td></td>";
    foreach ($columns[$tn] as $key => $column) {
        echo "<td>{$column['COLUMNNAME']}</td>";
    }
    if ($key < $max_columns - 1) {
        echo "<td colspan=\"" . ($max_columns - $key - 1) . "\"></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

Output (for your sample data)

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>MYFIRSTTABLE</td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>MYFIRSTFIELD</td>
    <td>MYSECONDFIELD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ANOTHERTABLE</td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>ANOTHERFIELD</td>
    <td colspan="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/jBJ5C)